# Copiar um arquivo txt inteiro para uma string em C++

Tags: c++, arquivo, io

Existe alguma função que copia um arquivo `.txt` em disco e transfere ele inteiro para uma *string*, sem copiar caractere por caractere em C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma instância de [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) a partir de um [`std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), veja só:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    /* Abre Arquivo texto para leitura */
    ifstream ifs("arquivo.txt");

    /* Constroi string */
    string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    /* Exibe string */
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Simplificando em uma única função:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

string ler_arquivo( const string& arq )
{
    ifstream ifs(arq.c_str());
    string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return str;
}

int main( void )
{
    string str = ler_arquivo( "arquivo.txt" );
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, preciso estudar mais  #include <streambuf>, mas no trecho que código que vc postou, conseguir entender

Answer (score 3):

Exatamente como está falando não tem, mas algo próximo sim. Na verdade tem um conjunto de ferramentas para acesso á arquivos. Precisa estudar e dominar todas elas para montar do jeito que deseja.

Veja [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Comment: não domino java , estou estudando um codigo de compressao de arquivos em java e vi que em java exite uma ferramenta mais rapido para fazer o que falei acima . usando a biblioteca ifstream consigo copiar caracter a caracter,  achei que existia um jeito mai eficaz.  de qualquer forma obrigado

Comment: Na verdade tem, é que você não quis estudar o que te passei, não é o que você está falando. POsso te garantir que não consegue copiar de forma mais eficiente em Java (também a diferença será ínfima), apenas tem algo mais pronto para uso.

Comment: okk , estou estudando isso  nesse momento!! mas de qualquer forma obrigado!